# htaccess rewriteRule in variable subfolder in different servers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building an API, this will be stored in different folders in different  servers and will have different versions, for example, I would like to turn this url:

```
http://aserver.com/api/v3/something
```

into this:

```
http://aserver.com/api/v3/index.php?endpoint=something&version=3
```

And this url:

```
http://leserver4.com/afolder/api/v6/someone
```

into this:

```
http://leserver4.com/afolder/api/v6/index.php?endpoint=someone&version=6
```

As you can see, the only common delimiter is this string: "/api/v"

I want be able to handle this in any folder and send the version number, so I made this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/v(\d+)/([^.]+)$ api/v$1/index.php?endpoint=$2&version=$1 [QSA,L,NC] # by anubhava
```

But is not working, it shows error 404

I configured apache2.conf this way:

```
<Directory "/var/www/*/api">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

what am I doing wrong?

---

I edited the question to include the configuration file and the whole .htaccess file

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and where is your `index.php` file located?

Comment: .htaccess is located in the root folder (in both examples is http;//aserver.com/.htaccess and http;//leserver4.com/.htaccess), index.php is located under api/v#/ folder, where # is any number.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use just L in the end of the string?

Comment: Can you try this rule: `RewriteRule ^api/v(\d+)/([^.]+)$ api/v$1/index.php?endpoint=$2&version=$1 [QSA,L,NC]`

Comment: Thank you, but still not working, I going to edit my question to include the whole htaccess file and apache config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `.htaccess` inside `api/` directory with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^v(\d+)/([^.]+)$ v$1/index.php?endpoint=$2&version=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```